# Installation failed trying to install MySQL ODBC connector on macOS High Sierra

Tags: odbc, pyodbc, unixodbc, macos-high-sierra, mysql-odbc-connector

I'm trying to install [this mysql odbc connector](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/) on my macOS High Sierra machine, but I get this error:
[image]

I tried installing it using `installer` in the hopes of getting information about what went wrong:

```
➜  ~ sudo installer -pkg Desktop/mysql-connector-odbc-5.3.9-macos10.12-x86-64bit.pkg -target / -verbose
installer: Package name is MySQL Connector/Odbc 5.3.9
installer: Installing at base path /
installer: Preparing for installation….....
installer: Preparing the disk….....
installer: Preparing MySQL Connector/Odbc 5.3.9….....
installer: Waiting for other installations to complete….....
installer: Configuring the installation….....
installer:
#
installer: Validating packages….....
#
installer: The install failed (The Installer encountered an error that caused the installation to fail. Contact the software manufacturer for assistance.)
```

But that doesn't help. Do you have any tips on how I can debug this and get the connector installed? Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I just noticed this:
[image]
on this page: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/connector-odbc-installation-binary-osx.html

After installing iODBC (http://www.iodbc.org/dataspace/doc/iodbc/wiki/iodbcWiki/Downloads) it was able to install the connector.

Comment: Still found that even with following the steps as outlined on the iODBC Wiki and mySQLWorkbench the system fails to find the ODBC Administrator from the migration wizard

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm reviving an old thread, but having just had this exact problem/issue, and not solving with the iodbc installation, I thought I'd post the solution that worked for me.  Use the commmand line...  open terminal and run...

```
pip install mysql-connector-python
```

or

```
pip install mysql-connector
```

Answer (score 1):

For those on an Apple Silicone Mac, this might be caused by having the wrong version of iODBC installed. Make sure to install the one labeled `arm64` from [iODBS website](https://www.iodbc.org/dataspace/doc/iodbc/wiki/iodbcWiki/Downloads#Mac%20OS%20X)